# C++ x+=1 x++ and x = x +1 are not the same?

Tags: c++

I can not grasp the concept as to how these statements produce different values. As far as I know x+=1, means x = x + 1. I also know that x++ should be equivalent to x + 1.

I've also searched this topic and found posts which ask the same question, those posts are answered usually by stating the statements/expressions are the same, but the different result was due to another code mistake. With the example I will provide I don't see how there is a code mistake so please explain, thank you.

```
int x = 0;
x++;
```

x should be 1 at this point because x++ adds 1 to x.

So why is it that if I assign x to 0, and then proceed to code "cout << x++;" I get a value of 0 on the screen?!. How does x++ become 0 if x++ is equal to x+1 and if x is 0 then 1+0=1? I've been told its due to ++ being put after x, but why does that matter if dealing with addition 1 + 0 is the same as 0 + 1?

Comment: You put the `++` after the `x`, which means that you want the increment to occur after the value of the expression is determined. If you want the increment to occur first, use `++x`. C++ is not math. Symbols do not have to mean in C++ what they mean in mathematics.

Comment: Voting to re-open.  The question linked to rationalize why this post was closed, i.e. about post and pre increments (`i++` & `++i`) does not include any discussion explaining the differences between the following expressions and statement:   `x+=1`  `x++` and `x = x +1` .  These _are not_ duplicate questions by any means.

Answer (score 4):

`cout << x++;` outputs the value of `x` before the increment as you are using the postfix increment operator.

`cout << ++x;` would do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms of the `++` operator: prefix and postfix. You're using the postfix form.

`x++` returns the *current* value of x, then increments it. When you use `cout << x++`, it prints x *then* increments it.

`++x` does what you want: it increments x *then* returns it. `cout << ++x` will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`x++` simply returns `x` and then increases `x` by one.

So `cout << x++` in your example would be the equivalent of `cout << x; x = x+ 1;`

Comment: Okay I understand now that cout << x++; just returns x then adds 1 to it. But if that is the case how come if I cout << x++; << x; I still get 0? Seems like 1 never got added to x.

Comment: Does `cout << x++; << x;` compile?

Comment: Yes it becomes "00" on my screen

Comment: It does not compile - see https://ideone.com/5qzjZM

Comment: it does for me, here is my code.  
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int x = 0;






int main()
{


    cout << x++ << x;
    return 0;
}

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @EdHeal remove the ; after x++  in  "cout << x++; <<x;"
It should compile.

Comment: @bob The problem with your code is that "int x = 0" is not inside the main() function. So you have a global variable. Use the following code and you will see that it does increment properly. I included your x variable and added a y variable inside main().
" #include <iostream> using namespace std; int x = 0; int main() { int y = 0; cout << x++ << x; cout << endl; cout << y++ << y; return 0; } "

Comment: @bob
Here are some links on how to modify global variable from within main()
https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/local-global-and-static-variables-in-c/  and this https://www.includehelp.com/code-snippets/c-program-to-define-modify-and-access-a-global-variable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's post-increment, which means that it will execute the variable as-is, and then add to the variable.

Had you tried the pre-increment `++x`, then it would add to the variable, and execute the variable as-is (which is now incremented).

Therefore, `int x = 0; x = x + 1; cout << x;` and `int x = 0; x++; cout << x++;` will all print `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Cout << x++ will first print x and then increase it, x++ is post increment so after the operation x is increased. Instead ++x will do the opposite. And also if you cout some expression like x+1 the expression will be evaluated before printing

Answer (score 0):

x++ is a post increment, which means that it increments after it has run the current statement.

In contrast, ++x executes the current statement before executing the increment.

Hope this helps.